# BottomNavigationView set to non-clickable

Tags: java, android, bottomnavigationview

I have a BottomNavigationView in my main activity and I have tried everything to try to make the buttons (items) un-clickable.

In main_menu of the BottomNavigationView I have:

```
  android:clickable="false"
  android:contextClickable="false"
```

In each Item.....

In the java I have:

```
    bottomNavigationView.setEnabled(false);
    bottomNavigationView.setFocusable(false);
    bottomNavigationView.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
    bottomNavigationView.setClickable(false);
    bottomNavigationView.setContextClickable(false);
    bottomNavigationView.setOnClickListener(null);
```

The Items are still clickable......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not my answer,but should work

```
setCheckable(false) for first item

navigation.getMenu().getItem(0).setCheckable(false);

item.setCheckable(true) inside onNavigationItemSelected()

public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.navigation_home:
        item.setCheckable(true);
        mTextMessage.setText(R.string.title_home);
        return true;
}
return false;
}
```